# instagrapi how to check new direct message?

Tags: python, instagrapi

**Guys who is know how check new direct messagee from instagram
**
I want to run code in real time and read new unreaded messages from instagram.

```
import json
from instagrapi import Client
from instagrapi.types import StoryMention, StoryMedia, StoryLink, StoryHashtag

def get_user_access(data):
    with open(data, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        f = json.load(file)
        return f['login'], f['password']

USERNAME, PASSWORD = get_user_access('data.json') 

cl = Client()
cl.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

user_id = cl.user_id_from_username(USERNAME)
thread = cl.direct_threads(1)

messages = cl.direct_threads(amount=10)

for message in messages:
    text = message.messages[0].text
    user_id = message.messages[0].user_id
    username = cl.user_info(user_id).username
    print(message.messages[0].text)
```

Comment: are you storing usernames and passwords in a plain json file? that's not a great idea. If this file is compromised all logins are leaked.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.